# Spring-boot Actuator SSL configuration

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8, spring-boot-actuator

I'm developing a webapplication with Spring-boot using embedded tomcat.
One of the requirements of this app is 2-way SSL (clientAuth).

Enabling ClientAuth is easy enough however we also like to use spring-boot Actuator for management of the app on a different port without clientAuth.

Is there is a clean way to do this?

(Disabling SSL on the actuator endpoints would also be enough)

Comment: Looking at the source of `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration` i see a `ServerProperties` is injected From the beanFactory, but my Spring experience is too limited to work out how/if i can influence this which bean is actualy injected there, or how i could get a hold of the bean to configure it.

Comment: It should be possible by config http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-management-specific-ssl

Comment: Must have been in a update to spring boot since i asked this question, thanks. (you can make it a answer if you like)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to latest spring docs, you can use

```
management.server.port=8080
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
```

in the properties to configure the management ports. see [production-ready-management-specific-ssl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-management-specific-ssl) in the spring boot doc for more options.

Comment: Why isn't it possible to do the same without using a different port?

Comment: @PatPatPat Using a different port allows you to separate the management webapp from the main webapp. If you want to use the same port, you need to enable/disable SSL globally for your application